# How to run oninput function of 2nd input tag from 1st input tag`s function

Tags: jquery, html

I want to run oninput function of 2nd input tag from 1st input tags function. That works with onchange function of 2nd input tags function. 
There is an example of onchange function : - [.onChange()](https://codepen.io/st-skumar/pen/qBEyaZp?editors=1010)

> **HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="a"/>
<input type="text" id="b"/>
```

> *JQuery* **it is works**

```
$('#a').on("change",function() {
    $('#b').change();
});

$('#b').on("change",function() {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

but the problem is, When i changed `$('#b').change();` to `$('#b').input();` its nothing works.

oninput example is there : -

> *JQuery* **it is nothing works**

```
$('#a').on("change",function() {
    $('#b').input();
});

$('#b').on("input",function() {
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

Please tell me the Solution of this Problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no input() method in jQuery. The error in the console should state: 'input is not a function"'. Use should use `trigger`

```js
$('#a').on("change",function() {
    $('#b').trigger('input');
});

$('#b').on("input",function() {
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a" />
<input type="text" id="b" />
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you must trigger "input". Instead of `$('#b').input()` try using `$('#b').trigger("input")`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Trigger](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_trigger.asp) to trigger specific events.

```
$('#a').on("change",function() {
    $('#b').trigger("input");
});

$('#b').on("input",function() {
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would say to extract the method to avoid funneling all your logic through the DOM.

```
function alertB () {
  alert($b.index());
}

var $b = $('#b').on("input", alertB);

$('#a').on("change", alertB);
```